# opencart 3.0.1.1 filename.ocmod.xml invalid file type

Tags: opencart, frontend

In opencart 3.0.1.1 when i upload  filename.ocmod.xml from extension installer from admin panel it gives me "invalid file type error". How can I fix this error?

Comment: Please mention your ocmod file code. also, please read here for How do I ask a good question? - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

3.x support only archived files, You need to archive the file before upload .
eg: change the xml file name to 'install.xml' then archive the file as filename.ocmod.zip.