# OCmod doesn't work/overwrite files in OpenCart 3.0.1.1

Tags: xml, mod-rewrite, twig, opencart, ocmod

I am trying to mod the admin in OpenCart (3.0.1.1) slightly.  I have written the following XML code as a test to see if I can mod the product form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<modification>
    <name>Test</name>
    <code>Test</code>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <author>Test</author>
    <link>http://web.com</link>
    <file path="admin/view/template/catalog/product_form.twig">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[
            <div id="content">
            ]]></search>
            <add position="replace"><![CDATA[
            <div id="content" class="yeah">
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
</modification>
```

Because I can't get the Extensions Installer to upload an XML file ([separate issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44970759/opencart-3-0-1-1-filename-ocmod-xml-invalid-file-type/44987531#44987531)) I have to save the xml file and install.xml in a folder along side an empty upload folder and then zip the parent folder like you would with a more complex mod.  This works - ie it uploads and installs:

[image: upload success]

I then go to the Modification List and refresh to see there is nothing there (an no reference in the Log either):
[image: nothing in mod list]

And, of course, the mod hasn't worked:

[image: mod hasn't worked]

Any ideas?

Comment: I have testing this issue. & same issue created for me. So, I think, this issue is by default in this version. also, I think We will need to wait some days for stable new OpenCart version. because, I have realized. has been released OpenCart version 3.0.1.2 two days ago. and also,  3.0.1.3 (Beta) version in progress.

Comment: Thanks Hamish.  I'm upgrading to 3.0.1.2 now and I'll see if that helps.

Comment: I upgraded to 3.0.1.2 and still the same issue.  OC mod doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: You can add your issue in github. you will get reply by OpenCart. https://github.com/opencart/opencart/issues

Answer (score 3):

3.x support only archived files, You need to archive the file before upload . eg: change the xml file name to 'install.xml' then archive the file as filename.ocmod.zip.

Comment: Wow thanks, this info was lacking from the official documentation. It really makes testing modifications even harder than before

Answer (score 0):

I am explaining by example

Suppose we have an extension that has the following files as
upload
install.xml

then we need to zip both files as extension_name.ocmod.zip.
But if we extract this zip file, then files should not be extracted in the extension_name directory.

The .ocmod.zip file should contain the following at its root:
upload
install.xml

Hope it will solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

do not leave spaces  in search tags. The code should look like this: <?xml

```
version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<modification>
    <name>Test</name>
    <code>Test</code>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <author>Test</author>
    <link>http://web.com</link>
    <file path="admin/view/template/catalog/product_form.twig">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[<div id="content">]]></search>
            <add position="replace"><![CDATA[
            <div id="content" class="yeah">
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
</modification>
```